# Como limitar o tamanho do Body para ficar centralizado na tela em Css

Tags: html, css, body

```
body{
    font-family: gotham, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Comment: olha, acredito que não tenha como não viu... o que você pode fazer é colocar algo dentro da body e colocar o tamanho que você quer e centralizar.

Comment: Realmente acredito que não tenha como mesmo, tenta colocar tudo dentro de uma div

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira simples para centrar seu conteúdo em uma janela do navegador é aplicar algum CSS à tag `body`. A propriedade `max-width` faz exatamente o que é dito, ela define uma largura máxima. O `margin "0"` define a margem superior e inferior e o "auto" define a margem direita e esquerda.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    max-width: 400px;
    font-family: gotham, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

div {
    background: azure;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo aos comentários, é possível ? Sim, veja alguns exemplos:

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
html {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
body {
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
Conteudo da página.
```

> Obs.: Ao limitar a largura do corpo do documento, a propriedade *background / background-color* não se aplicará a largura e sim ao documento todo.

#### Exemplo sem fundo

```css
html {
  height: 100%; /* Define o tamanho do Documento HTML */
}
body {
  border: 2px solid #069;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Centraliza */
  padding: 8px;
  width: 70%; /* Define a largura do Corpo do Documento */
}
```

```html
Seu conteúdo aqui!
```

#### Exemplo com fundo

```css
html {
  height: 100%; /* Define o tamanho do Documento HTML */
}
body {
  background: #e3e3e3;
  border: 2px solid #069;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Centraliza */
  padding: 8px;
  width: 70%; /* Define a largura do Corpo do Documento */
}
```

```html
Seu conteúdo aqui!
```

Note que a cor do fundo não se limitou a largura informada, para corrigir esse problema, defina a cor de fundo do documento:

```
html {
    background: #fff; /* Cor do fundo do documento */
    height: 100%; /* Define o tamanho do Documento HTML */
}
```

#### Fundo corrigido

```css
html {
    background: #fff; /* Cor do fundo do documento */
    height: 100%; /* Define o tamanho do Documento HTML */
}
body {
  background: #e3e3e3; /* Cor do fundo do corpo */
  border: 2px solid #069;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Centraliza */
  padding: 8px;
  width: 70%; /* Define a largura do Corpo do Documento */
}
```

```html
Seu conteúdo aqui!
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que limitar o tamanho do Body em si não seja uma boa prática, porém, você pode criar uma classe para centralizar o conteúdo.

```
.container {
   position: relative;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 1230px;
}
```

E utilizando Media Queries você consegue deixar este container responsivo:

```
@media (max-width: 1920px){
  .container {
    width: 1230px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px){
  .container {
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.container {
   position: relative;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

A utilização ébem simples, somente criar uma div com esta classe e ela já ira centralizar o conteúdo.

```
<body>
     <div class="container">
         <p>Seu conteúdo aqui!</p>
     </div>
</body>
```

É um padrão fortemente aceito utilizado em diversos frameworks. Caso queira se aprofundar mais recomendo fortemente utilizar o Bootstrap, ele irá te ajudar muito. :D

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#overview-container

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download